# "Databricks-connect test" process not ending

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks connect (Windows O.S) but when i try to test the connection i.e. databricks-connect Test , it keeps on running.

However when i terminate the test manually and then write a pyspark command it throws a proxy error :

```
    19/05/13 09:38:42 ERROR HTTPClient: Failed to set proxy config 
    '123456678:345697852@webgateway.mmm.nnnn.com:9090', it should be of 
    format 'HOST:PORT'.
    scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@89a3a8 (of class 
    [Ljava.lang.String;)
```

[similarity of code as shown in documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAqWl.jpg)

i followed the available docummentation and the output of my code is similar but it just keeps running.
Can anyone guide me how to resolve it ?

Comment: I don't think DBConnect supports networks on a proxy right now. Though it is on the cards. Can you try from a different network?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Simon. I will try from a "proxy free device" may be it will work. By the way do you know when it will support proxy networks? I tried to find related project on Github but didn't found any thing related to dbconnect. do you have any idea if there exists a repository or any related open issues so that i can stay notified when the issue is worked upon?  Thanks for your help once again.